# The authorityKeyIdentifier does not get accepted

Tags: openssl

I am trying to generate CSR for the last hours with the following openssl statement:

```
openssl req -new \
            -sha256 \
            -subj "/C=YY/ST=Anywhere/L=downtown/O=test/OU=Test Inc./CN=test.io" \
            -addext "subjectKeyIdentifier = hash" \
            -addext "authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer" \
            -addext "basicConstraints = critical, CA:true" \
            -addext "keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign" \
            -key key.pem \
            -out csr.pem
```

Unfortunately, it complains:

```
Error Loading command line extensions
8686967616:error:22FFF079:X509 V3 routines:func(4095):reason(121):/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/97f6331a-ba75-11ed-a4bc-863efbbaf80d/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/crypto/x509/x509_akey.c:184:
8686967616:error:22FFF080:X509 V3 routines:func(4095):reason(128):/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/97f6331a-ba75-11ed-a4bc-863efbbaf80d/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/crypto/x509/x509_conf.c:100:name=authorityKeyIdentifier, value=keyid,issuer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `issuer` asks OpenSSL to copy the DN from the issuing certificate... and there is no issuing certificate *yet* if you're just generating a CSR – it will only become known sometime in the future, when the CSR is given to a CA to sign.

If you are creating a root CA, there is no point in generating a CSR at all (there's no other CA to give it to); you want to use the **`-x509`** option to directly output a self-signed certificate.

Meanwhile, if you're creating a subordinate CA (intermediate CA) just skip the extension. Typically, the CA itself will decide on which extensions to add according to its profiles and will ignore most extensions from your CSR anyway.

(Also – most CAs don't put the issuer directoryName in authorityKeyIdentifier, as there is no global directory to look up the DN in; it's good enough to just set it to `keyid:always`.)